# Resuming a C# application after system restart

Tags: c#, wpf

I wrote a simple c# wpf code as below,

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
   private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Content = "Before restart";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "-r"); //restart
        label2.Content = "After restart";

    }
```

}

Now the problem is I wanted to resume my application automatically after restart and and display message as "After restart". Please help me how to achieve this...

Comment: Have you put your application into the `AutoStart` folder or `Run` registry key or anything similar?

Comment: _"I wanted to resume my application automatically after restart"_ - explain. If you're for example building a POS terminal, you might want to look into kiosk mode. You can't just resume an application at an arbitrary point anyway, you'll have to store the state at shutdown and restore that after a restart.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem is maintain the state in hard disk or some permanent memory like custom transaction file.

For e.g.

There will be different stage in the application. I will enter each stage after processing into file. one the machine is stopped then if the application launch automatically it will read the stage from this file and then process from that stage.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Read stage from transaction file as **Stage**
    if(Stage == Stage1)
    {
        label1.Content = "Before restart";
        WriteTransaction(Stage2);
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "-r"); //restart
    if(Stage == Stage2)
    {
        label2.Content = "After restart";
        //Finish transaction and delete the transaction file.
    }

}
```

This way you can solve the problem.

To restart the application automatically you can put your executable under start up folder or even you can think of making it as windows service.

Comment: Thank you for your valueable suggestion. I'l try to put the state of application in some text or XML file. May I know how to put my executables under start up to restart my application?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concept (pseudo code):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // initialize defaults
    bool isRestarted = false;
    label1.Content = "";
    label2.Content = "";

    // Check the state
    if (stateFile.Exists) // stateFile is something like type FileInfo
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(stateFile.FullName);
        isRestarted = ParseForBool(text);
        label1.Content = ParseForLabel(text); // if you want that to be restored as well
    }

    if (isRestarted)
    {
        label2.Content = "After restart";
        DoSomeMagicRemoveAutostart(); // just if you want to restart only once
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Content = "Before restart";
        stateFile.Write(true); // is restarted
        stateFile.Write(label1.Content); // if you want to restore that as well
        DoSomeMagicAutoStartOperation(); // TODO: Autostart folder or Registry key
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "-r"); //restart
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two choices: Adding the application to Startup Folder or adding the appropiate key to the run key in Windows registry.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That's not the full truth. After restarting it does not show "After restart" but "Before restart".